# Help me understand pack(), openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() and mt_rand() for salting passwords

Tags: php, algorithm, random, salt

I'm building an application that will have a user base, and I'm at the point of securing the login. I'm fairly new to programming (and PHP,) but my efforts thus far have pointed to using `Crypt()` and a Blowfish hashed salt.

Before I go further, let me specify that **I am not interested in phpass** at this time.

Within the `crypt()` documentation, a user recently posted this:

```
<?php 
   $salt = substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(pack('N4', mt_rand(), mt_rand(), mt_rand(), mt_rand()))), 0, 22); 
?>
```

> It is intended for use on systems
>   where mt_getrandmax() == 2147483647.
>
> The salt created will be 128 bits in
>   length, padded to 132 bits and then
>   expressed in 22 base64 characters. 
>   (CRYPT_BLOWFISH only uses 128 bits for
>   the salt, even though there are 132
>   bits in 22 base64 characters.  If you
>   examine the CRYPT_BLOWFISH input and
>   output, you can see that it ignores
>   the last four bits on input, and sets
>   them to zero on output.)
>
> Note that the high-order bits of the
>   four 32-bit dwords returned by
>   mt_rand() will always be zero (since
>   mt_getrandmax == 2^31), so only 124 of
>   the 128 bits will be pseudorandom.  I
>   found that acceptable for my
>   application.

I tested my server, and indeed mt_getrandmax() returns 2147483647.  I tried poking around the documentation to understand what the above code really does--the `pack()` code N4 is for a 32-bit string (big endian byte order??) repeated 4 times... which I assume is why there's 4 `mt_rand()` arguments.

What I don't understand is why he replaces `+` with `.` and the purpose of 22 base64 characters (not that I fully understand what base64 is.)

It was recommended that I look into `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` for my random salt generation, as the previous method I was looking at was limiting itself to just `1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

Supposedly there was a bug pre [5.3.4](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.4) causing `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` to run painfully slow, occassionally causing timeout errors. I'm not sure if I should try to use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` with `Crypt()` or something like the above method using `mt_rand()` and `pack()`.

I'm trying to understand more how all these elements work, and what they are doing conceptually--rather than just using one without understanding it to achieve my goal; I'm trying to learn :P

Can someone help me understand the different elements at work here, or at least direct me to a knowledge base where I can read about it? I think the most eluding component is understanding the different formats/terminology (base64, ascii, hexdec, bit, byte, etc.) but also in the end, how to achieve a fairly secure salt for use with my passwords.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me start of by saying that there is nothing special about a salt from the standpoint of generation.  It's just another random string.  It's special in how it's used, but not generated.

### Your specific questions

1. Why does he replace `+` with `.`?

   I have no idea.  Perhaps it's because the `+` character may be confused with a space in urls.  But a salt should never be in a url, so that's likely not it.
2. What does base64/hexdec do:

   Base64 converts a raw byte stream (each byte having values from 0 to 255) into a base 64 representation.  There are plenty of resources on it, so it's not worth going deep into.  Read [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more information.

   `hexdec` converts a hex number (a-f0-9) into a decimal one.  It converts from base 16 to base 10 (just another way of representing numbers).
3. What is a bit and byte:

   A bit is a single unit of information.  It has 2 states, 0 or 1.  A Byte is a series of 8 bits.  So a byte can have 256 unique combinations. Read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)...
4. What is ascii

   It's a character set.  It represents a single printable character in a single 8-bit byte.  Again, I'd suggest reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

### Salts in General

The goal of a good salt generation function is large entropy.  That means that the number of possible outputs is as large as possible.  So any method should produce a large set of results.

Now, you need to define what are acceptable characters for the salt (since you'll need to store the salt to verify the hash).  The best possible salts are full-byte numbers and not just displayable characters.  Now, you won't be able to display this in a meaningful manor, but you don't need to display it.  Plus, for storage, you could always use `base64_encode` it.

Next, you need to choose how big you want the salt to be.  The bigger the salt is, the better.  A 32 character salt is acceptable, but a 128 character salt is better.  The size of the salt, and the number of options per character will dictate the number of possibilities there are.  Some common combinations:

```
Hex, 32 characters: 2e38 possibilities
Hex, 128 characters: 1e154 possibilities
Full Byte, 32 characters: 1e77 possibilities
Full Byte, 128 characters: 1e308 possibilities
```

Now, you need to generate the salt.  The key is to do as many random calls as necessary to fill out the entropy.  You can do this a few ways:

- System Dependent (only works on *nix but best entropy):

  ```
  $f = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
  $seed = fgets($f, $characters); // note that this will always return full bytes
  fclose($f);
  ```
- Library dependent (good, but requires OpenSSL to be installed)

  ```
  $seed = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($characters);
  ```
- fallback

  ```
  $seed = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $characters; $i++) {
      $seed .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
  }
  ```

Now, you need to convert it into the desired output format.

- Hex (a-f0-9):

  ```
  $out = '';
  for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($seed); $i < $len; $i++) {
      $num = ord($seed);
      $out .= dechex(floor($num / 16)) . dechex($num % 16);
  }
  ```
- Base36 (a-z0-9):

  ```
  $out = '';
  for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($seed); $i < $len; $i++) {
      $num = ord($seed);
      $out .= base_convert($num, 10, 36);
  }
  ```
- Base64 (a-zA-Z0-9+=):

  ```
  $out = base64_encode($seed);
  ```
- Full Byte:

  Nothing is necessary since it's already in this format.

Comment: @ircmaxell - Thanks for taking the time to respond--hopefully you don't mind if I have a few more questions: So there are 256 unique bytes (0-255), each composed of eight 0/1 combinations. If I were to use `chr()` to display an ascii character--that implies to me that there are 256 ascii codes, but it says there are 128 with 33 control codes... what about the remainers? or multiple byte characters?

Comment: @ircmaxell - 32 characters vs 128 characters? is character synonymous with bits? 32-bit vs 32-character? If they say 128-bit encryption, does that mean it's 128-characters long? Also, what is the `e` in your possible combinations example? a comma?

Comment: ASCII itself only uses code points 0 to 127 (it's a 7 bit character set).  The 8th bit goes unused in traditional ASCII.  However, ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) uses the 8th bit to add the additional 128 code-points.  So when we use `chr()`, we're converting a number from 0 to 255 into the associated binary byte as a string (so 65 becomes the codepoint 65 which is the letter A).  It's really more complicated than that since code-points have values without using a character-set, but in PHP we don't need to make that distinction.  Just think that `chr()` converts a number to the associated code-point.

Comment: @Julian: `e` is scientific notation (`1e2` is `1 x 10^2` which is `100`, `1e308` is `1 x 10^308` which is 1 followed by 308 `0`'s.  Characters means symbols.  It's not equivalent to bits.  128 bits is not necessarily 128 characters.  128 bits displayed in Hex (a-f0-9) is 32 characters.  128 bits displayed in full byte characters (0-255 code points) is 16 characters.  When they say the number of bits, it's the number of unique possible combinations.  So 128bit has `2^128` or `3.4e38` combinations.

Comment: Ah, the scientific notion is coming back to me--it's been too long since I've dealt with it. I want a lynda.com training video on computer science lol... Thanks for your help--I could keep the questions coming, but this isn't ircmaxelloverflow ;)

Comment: @Julian: Search (there are tons of resources on this site here) or ask a new question if you can't find what you're looking for.